# Place observable into a condition in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, guard

I'm trying to make a loging system based on my api, 
I created 3 functions : 
me() : returns the user profile with the token
isloggedin() returns a boolean observable, based on : has the me() request data.success (has been the token accepted by the api)
Finally, I use it in my angular guard;

I have:

```
    console.log("triggered");
    if(localStorage.getItem('token') && localStorage.getItem('logged') == "True"){
      let meOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json',
          'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token'),
        })
      };
    return this.http.get<user>('https://localhost:3000/user/me', meOptions);
  }else{
    return of(new user(false, "",""));
  }

  }
isloggedin():Observable<boolean>{
  return this.me().pipe(map(data=>{ //pipe sur undefined 
    console.log(data);
    if(data.success){
      console.log("renvoie oui")
      return true; 
    }else{
      console.log("renvoie non")
      return false;
    }
  }))
}
```

I verified :

```
   this.auth.isloggedin().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
    })
```

- Returns true or false
  But, when it comes into the observable:

````
    if(this.auth.isloggedin()){
      console.log("You logged - guard")
      return true;

    }else{
      console.log("Kick by guard ! Not logged - guard")
      this.router.navigate(["auth"]);
      return false;
    }
  }```
Everytime, the guard returns "logged", even when the isloggedin() tells that the user isn't loggedin,
what am I doing wrong ? How to correct it ?
Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

you return your observable to guards and let them handle the subscribing...

```
return this.auth.isLoggedIn().pipe(
  tap(loggedIn => {
    if (!loggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['auth']);
    }
  })
)
```

Comment: Hello ;) should i subscribe in this case ? Thanks

Comment: no. guards subscribed to the returned observable and use the value. you never subscribe in a guard

Answer (score -1):

Isn't a big thing, with your if statement you're acessing the observable, not the value. Just replace that if with that:

```
if(this.auth.isloggedin().value){
  console.log("You logged - guard")
  return true;

}
```

edit 1:

Sorry, I'm using that answer expecting a subject, not a observable. You must really subscribe in that case.

edit 2:

In that case, you could just subscribe in that Observable and assing his value to a property inside your class and make a if statement using that property instead of that observable like:

```
bool

ngOnInit() {
    subscription =  this.auth.isloggedin().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.bool = data;
    });
}

method() {
    if(this.bool) {
    your code...
    } else {
    your code...
    }
}
```

edit 3:

Don't forget to unsubscribe

edit 4:

Sorry, I didn't realize that was a http request. But the concept is the same, you need to update bool (subscribing to isLoggedIn) everytime you want to check if the user is logged. So... I think that will do:

```
bool: boolean;

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.checkUserIsLogged();
}

method() {
    if(this.bool) {
    your code...
    } else {
    your code...
    }
}

checkUserIsLogged(callback?){
    this.auth.isloggedin().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.bool = data;
    }, err => {}, () => {
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    });
}

facadeMethod() {
    this.checkUserIsLogged(() => {
        this.method();     
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just wonder : we subscribe in the nginit, but it's done once, because the request isn't done a few times, so the this.bool will stay false, don't we need to recall of the subscribe, or something like it ? Thanks